# In IntelliJ IDEA, how can I create a key binding that executes a shell script with the current file as a parameter?

Tags: java, javascript, shell, intellij-idea, key-bindings

In IntelliJ IDEA, how can I create a key binding that executes a shell script with the current file as a parameter?

For exanmple, if I am in a test file (entity.spec.js), I want to save and hit a key binding to trigger a shell script with that file as the parameter:

```
./run_test.sh /full/path/to/entity.spec.js
```

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 12):

You can do it using the [External Tools](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/external-tools.html). Then you can assign a keyboard shortcut to your tool in `Settings` | `Keymap`.

Please note that you should specify your shell interpreter as a **Program** for the external tool (such as `/bin/bash`) and pass your script path and the file name as **Parameters**.
Use **Insert Macro** button to add a macro for the current editor file path.

Comment: I'm trying to bind to S which is the same as save all.  If i remove the hotkey from save all it works, however if I don't remove the binding it does not.  This should be OK because IntelliJ saves as I type, correct?

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas it doesn't save as you type, it saves before run, before compilation, on exit, before commit, etc. There is also a setting to save files periodically.

Comment: Ok, in that case I need the double binding to work in order.  Do you know how i would do that?

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas sure, just record a macro with these 2 actions and assign a shortcut to the macro instead.