# How can I run .sh file in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm, sh

I want to run a sh file in pycharm and I have installed "Bash Support" plugin, but I don't know how to set configurations and it hints:"Run configuration Error:No interpreter path given". 
Could anyone tell me how to do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I run a shell script instead of python in a PyCharm run configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30841383/how-can-i-run-a-shell-script-instead-of-python-in-a-pycharm-run-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try [2019.2 EAP PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/nextversion/) version. It bundles [new shell plugin](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2019/06/intellij-idea-2019-2-eap2-shell-script-support-improved-code-duplicates-detection-services-tool-window-and-more/) which is more powerful and is actively supported.

There should be a gutter icon to execute a script:

[image]

You can also create a Shell Script run configuration from **Run | Edit Configurations** top menu.